# Vuejs Passing data to select element from ajax request not reactive

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2

I am trying to make dynamic select input that populates it's option elements depending on the the response of ajax with the following code. Everything is working fine if the data is hardcoded however when I try to make option dynamic based on the response I don't get reactivity.

In short let's say I have an object **{Foo: 'Bar', Lorem: 'Ipsum'}** I get

```
<select>
  <option value="Foo">Bar</option>
  <option value="Lorem">Ipsum</option>
</select>
```

My problem is when I want to make the data dynamic using the function below I still get the same option even though I now have **{Enet: 'Dolor', Magna: 'Aliqua', mollit: 'Anim'}** Is there a better approach to this? Or Am I missing Something.

*Function responsible for populating the object:*

```
$.get('/registrar/levels', function (data) {
   for (const datum of data) {
     addModal.levelFields[datum.name] = datum.id;
   }
});
```

*The component:*

```
Vue.component("modal-add-form", {
props: {
    formName: String,
    formType: [String, Number],
    options: Object,
},
template: `<div class="form-group" v-if="formType !== 'select'">
                <label :for="formName" v-text="formName"></label>
                <input :type="formType" class="form-control" :name="formName" :id="formName" value="" :placeholder="formName">
            </div>

            <div v-else>
                <select :name="formName" class="form-control">
                    <option v-for="(value, name) in options" :value="value" v-text="name"></option>
                </select>
            </div>`

});
```

Comment: You're setting properties of `addModal.levelFields` in the callback. How does that relate to your component?

Comment: I  just simply pass **addModal.levelFields** to options props of my component to render dynamic options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't directly reassign data value because Vue cannot detect property additions and rerender view. You should do it via `Vue.set` or `this.$set` like this:

```
$.get('/registrar/levels', (data) => {
   for (const datum of data) {
     this.$set(this.addModal.levelFields, datum.name, datum.id)
     // addModal.levelFields[datum.name] = datum.id;
   }
});
```